# I cannot execute this windows batch job from task scheduler

Tags: windows, sap

I have tried to execute a batch job created by BODS (data services - ETL tool).
The challenge faced is that the batch file does not execute. Even if it does
the log file is not created so I cannot check whether the job runs or not.

I can confirm one thing, the purpose (end result) is not achieved so can confirm that the batch job does not run.

Batch job:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\SAPBUS~1\DATASE~1/bin/AL_RWJ~1.EXE  "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Data Services/log/DEV1_JOBSERVER/" -w "inet:XXXX:3500"  -C "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Data Services/log/Job_2.txt"
```

Text file:

```
 -PLocaleUTF8 -R"Developer1 Local.txt"  -G"db39" -r1000 -T14 -LocaleGV   -CtBatch -CmtXXXXXXXX01 -CaAdministrator -CjXXXXXX -Cp3500
```

FYI the batch file/text file/and developer.text file is generated by the BODS itself

Comment: The "batch job" that you're talking about is the line you've quoted above in a ".cmd" or ".bat" file-- correct? Is the user context you're running this under an "Administrator" on the machine you're attempting to execute it on?

Comment: Trying to get a SAP stack exchange started, check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products